# xcode does not see sdl framework when compiling on 10.7.4

Tags: osx-lion, sdl, xcode4.3

I've recently updated xcode to 4.3.3 with osx sdk 10.7.4 in it. After that I am unable to link with sdl.framework (1.2.15)
When I switch platfrom to 10.6 it links ok.
When I compile using xcode 4.3.2 with osx sdk 10.7 it also links ok.

Any ideas?

Here's linker output

```
ld: framework not found SDL
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in XCode 4.3.3. See http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2012/Jun/msg00062.html

As a workaround at /Library/Frameworks to the Frameworks search path:

[image: Adding Framework Search Path]

Comment: Thx, worked like a charm - for linking.
I've also had to change path to framework in copy frameworks build phase to absolute.

Comment: WHY this bug! doesn't make sense.